# Parse WhereEqualto pointer android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parse object id , I used it set a relation , and it worked , the result set a pointer to another class , I am now trying to retrieve a row using the WhereEqualto method , but I don't get anything when I test it , anyway I am pretty sure that the problem lies within the WhereEqualto method , because I tested to retrieve the result through WhereEqualto title let's say for example (a String row) , so my question is how to retrieve the Pointer row in the parse class .

```
  ParseQueryAdapter<Comment> adapter =
                new ParseQueryAdapter<Comment>(this, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Comment>() {
                    public ParseQuery<Comment> create() {
                        // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to our heart's desire.
                        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Comment");

  /*********      query.whereEqualTo("parent" ,ealId);   ************/

                        return query;
                    }
                });

        adapter.setTextKey("rating");
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter.loadObjects();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You pass in the parent object to your whereEqualTo as mentioned in the documentation https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational

Answer (score 0):

Your "parent" field is the pointer to a particular table so in `whereEqualTo()` method you need to pass a ParseObject of your pointer table.

For example, if you your parent field is the reference of the `_User` table then you must have to pass the reference of the `_User` table.

i.e. `query.whereEqualTo("parent",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());` something like this.